# Necessary normality assumptions for a one-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, assumptions

I am wondering about the normality assumption. It is required because underneat all this, ANOVA is running a F test. The denominator of the F test is the sd of the residuals, thus we need these residuals to be normally distributed.

This leaves me wondering about the numerator: the numerator is the variance of means of the factors (the k samples we are testing).

I have read that if the residuals are normally distributed, then, under the null (all population means are equal), the observed means also are, but I can not find any justification.

In fact, in the case where the samples have unequal sizes, and unequal variances, these k means belong to k different sampling distributions of the means, so they do not appear to be even i.d.

Could someone explain how we ensure that the numerator of the F statistic is also X2 distributed under the null?

Or do we just ignore the numerator, because it (usually, but not always) has such a small sample size (k is often small)?

I do know that the F test is robust to departures from normality, but... I am interested in the rigorous assumptions which would need to be satisfied to run a "mathematically" valid F test. How is normality of the k means ensured?